# Trying to rename rows of a matrix with a for

Tags: r, for-loop, paste

I'm trying to rename rows in a matrix as follows:

```
M = matrix(0,50,1)
nf = 50
for (k in 1:50) {
  filtro = k*(1/nf)
  rownames(M[k,]) <- paste("p.v",filtro)
}
```

it gives me the following error:

```
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = paste("p.v", filtro)) : 
attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions
```

Comment: you need `rownames(M)[k]` in your loop

Comment: just do `rownames(M) <- paste('p.v', 1:50 * 1/nf)`

Answer (score 3):

1. In general, you can't use `rownames(M[k,]) <- ...` instead you must use `rownames(M)[k] <- ...`. Why: the inner expression `M[k,]` returns a *vector*, which does not have a row name. What you are trying to do is change an attribute of the object `M`, so `rownames(M) <- ..` flows a little better.

   Internally, there is a function called `` `rownames<-` `` that changes row names for its first argument. Technically, its two arguments are `x` (matrix or frame) and `value` (the new name(s)); this is called even if subsequently indexed with `[` (as in bullet 2).
2. You can't use `rownames(.)[k] <- ...` because there are initially no row names, i.e., `rownames(M)` is initially `NULL`. You can get around this by assigning some names, even if arbitary:

   ```r
   rownames(M) <- seq(nrow(M)) # arbitrary, must be same length
   for (k in 1:50) {
     filtro = k*(1/nf)
     rownames(M)[k] <- paste("p.v",filtro)
   }
   ```
3. Better, though, use a vectorized approach, no `for` loop required:

   ```r
   rownames(M) <- paste("p.v", (1:50)/nf)
   head(M)
   #          [,1]
   # p.v 0.02    0
   # p.v 0.04    0
   # p.v 0.06    0
   # p.v 0.08    0
   # p.v 0.1     0
   # p.v 0.12    0
   ```

Comment: These for loops are still a mystery for me! Perfect!